# How do I get code coverage using Istanbul for typescript files?

Tags: code-coverage, istanbul

I am using Protractor as unit testing framework for my Angular2 project. All my test files are in the format of *.spec.js in respective module/component folders. I am using Istanbul for UT code coverage. Code coverage for spec files is working fine. But I want to cover complete codebase. That means I also want to include *.ts files under code coverage. How can I achiever this? There is very little available for covering .ts code. 
Note: I do not want to use grunt.

Directory structure:

```
root
|
|-package.json
|-protractor-config.js
|-public\
|--module1\
|---module.comp.ts
|---module.comp.html
|---module.comp.spec.js
|--module2\
|---module2.comp.ts
|---module2.comp.html
|---module2.comp.spec.js
```

package.json:

```
script {
    ...
    "coverage": "istanbul cover ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor-config.js",
    "test": "protractor protractor-config.js",
    ...
}
```

protractor-config.js

```
exports.config = {
    ...
    specs: ['public/**/*.spec.js'],
    ...
}
```

Edit: with above script block and protractor-config I am getting code coverage for UT files only.